# Call function on iframe parent window (window.top/window.parent) (circumvent cross-origin object access security)

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

Is there a way to circumvent the cross-origin security error that comes up when an iframe (domain **A**) on a page (domain **B**) tries to access properties of `window.top`?

I want to call a function, ie. `someFunc`, which belongs to domain B, through an event in the iframe of domain A, in the context of domain B.

Example:

**`a.com/index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var someFunc = t => document.querySelector("#test").text = t;
    </script>
    <span id="test">This is some dummy text.</span>
    <iframe src="https://b.com/index.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`b.com/index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Test</button>
    <script>
      document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        window.top.someFunc("This text has been changed through a cross-origin")
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example raises the following error on Firefox:
`SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "someFunc" on cross-origin object`

Comment: no.............

Comment: This is where you need to use postMessage and have code on both domains.

Comment: I know this must look silly but I appreciate the answer as I probably wouldn't have found postMessage otherwise... I'll write the answer in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to circumvent this is using [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) - Essentially, send a message from the iframe up to its parent window, which, if it has an event listener for `"message"`, can react accordingly.

ie.:

**`a.com/index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      let someFunc = t => document.querySelector("#test").text = t;
      window.addEventListener("message", event => someFunc(e.data));
    </script>
    <span id="test">This is some dummy text.</span>
    <iframe src="https://b.com/index.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`b.com/index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Test</button>
    <script>
      document.querySelector("#btn")
        .addEventListener("click", event => {
          window.parent.postMessage("Changed text", "http://a.com");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```